# PHP Stream - Get all HTTP request headers

Tags: php, http, http-headers, httprequest, httpresponse

I do a post request with the following code:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/';
$data = array('first-post-data' => 'data', 'second-post-data' => 'another-data');

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
        'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0',

        // corporate proxy thing ...
        'proxy' => 'proxy-ip:proxy-port',
        'request_fulluri' => true,
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$file = fopen($url, 'r', null, $context);
$content = stream_get_contents($file);

// Response headers:
echo '<pre>' . print_r(stream_get_meta_data($file), true) . '</pre>';

fclose($file);
echo $content;
```

I can easily get **response headers** from my handmade HTTP request with the function stream_get_meta_data. Is it possible to get all **request headers**? Are there any built-in function?

**EDIT**

I got the raw response headers with tcpflow: https://superuser.com/a/23187
Thanks!

Comment: In your case there are no request headers. All that in the context are in your options array.

Comment: Well, you're setting them in `$options` - so what's the question about?

Comment: Sorry, i meant, the RAW request headers ... I want to capture the entire request stream the way it arrives to server.

Answer (score -2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

Get all headers should do the trick for you - note though it is dependent on how certain php versions and methods of running php from your web server.

e.g.

```
PHP 5.4.0    This function became available under FastCGI. Previously, it was supported only when PHP was installed as an Apache module.
```

More Details are included on the link above.

Comment: It doesn't solve my issue. I need to get the raw request headers from fopen call, not from current page's request.